# container re-size to window

Tags: css

how do I make a container div that is 100% of browser window height minus 20 pixels at the top and bottom? so that there is always a margin of 20 at top/ bottom and never a need for a scroll bar. In CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could set the div to position: absolute and then set top and bottom to 20px. See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3kW3/

Comment: If the content goes higher than the viewport, it will go past it. Am not sure if this is what he wanted. use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It kind of worked but it needs to be centered and I need to get rid of that scroll bar. So i got this so far:  <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

html,body {height:100%;width:90%;}

#full {
 width:960px;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:pink;
 position:absolute;
 top:30px;
 bottom:30px;}
 
#content {
 height:900px;
 width:300px;
 background-color:#339;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="full"><div id="content"></div>
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>

Comment: What needs to be centered? That scrollbars appears because you have set  a width of 960px to #full.